# Issue with nested aggregations ElasticSearch : doing a sum after a max

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I know sub aggregation isn't possible with metric aggregations and that Elasticsearch supports sub aggregations with buckets. But I am a bit lost on how to do this.

I want to do a sum after nested aggregations and after having aggregated by max timestamp.

Something like the code below, give me this error : "Aggregator [max_date_aggs] of type [max] cannot accept sub-aggregations" which is normal. Is there a way to make it works?

```
{
"aggs": {
    "sender_comp_aggs": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "senderComponent"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "activity_mnemo_aggs": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "activityMnemo"
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "activity_instance_id_aggs": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field": "activityInstanceId"
                        },
                        "aggs": {
                            "business_date_aggs": {
                                "terms": {
                                    "field": "correlationIdSet.businessDate"
                                },
                                "aggs": {
                                    "context_set_id_closing_aggs": {
                                        "terms": {
                                            "field": "contextSetId.closing"
                                        },
                                        "aggs": {
                                            "max_date_aggs": {
                                                "max": {
                                                    "field": "timestamp"
                                                },
                                                "aggs" : {
                                                    "sum_done": {
                                                        "sum": {
                                                            "field": "itemNumberDone"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you would like to achieve, it helps if you also would have shared the mapping.

A bucket aggregation is about defining the buckets/groups. As you do in your example, you can wrap/nest bucket aggregations to further break down your buckets into sub-buckets and so on.

By default Elasticsearch always calculates the count-metric, but you can specify other metrics to get calculated as well. A metric is calculated per bucket / for a bucket (and not for another metric) this is why you cannot nest a metrics aggregation under a metric aggregation, it simply does not make sense.

Depending how your data looks like the only change you may need to do is, moving the `sum_done` aggregation out of the `aggs`-clause, to the same level as your `max_date_aggs`-aggregation.

**Code Snippet**

```
"aggs": {
  "max_date_aggs": { "max": {"field": "timestamp"} },
  "sum_done": { "sum": { "field": "itemNumberDone"} }
}
```

After you refined your question and you provided I managed to come up with a solution requiring one single request. As previously mentioned that `sum`-metric aggregation needs to operate on a bucket and not a metric. The solution is pretty straight forward: rather than calculating the `max`-date, just re-formulate this aggregation to a `terms`-aggregation, sorted by descending timestamp, asking for exactly one bucket.

**Solution**

```
GET gos_element/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "sender_comp_aggs": {
      "terms": {"field": "senderComponent.keyword"},
      "aggs": {
        "activity_mnemo_aggs": {
          "terms": {"field": "activityMnemo.keyword"},
          "aggs": {
            "activity_instance_id_aggs": {
              "terms": {"field": "activityInstanceId.keyword"},
              "aggs": {
                "business_date_aggs": {
                  "terms": {"field": "correlationIdSet.businessDate"},
                  "aggs": {
                    "context_set_id_closing_aggs": {
                      "terms": {"field": "contextSetId.closing.keyword"},
                      "aggs": {
                        "max_date_bucket_aggs": {
                          "terms": {
                            "field": "timestamp",
                            "size": 1, 
                            "order": {"_key": "desc"} 
                          },
                          "aggs": {
                            "sum_done": {
                              "sum": {"field": "itemNumberDone"}
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As I relied on the default Elasticsearch mapping, I had to refer to the `.keyword`-version of the fields. If your fields are directly mapped to a field of type `keyword`, you don't need to do that.

You can test the request above right away after indexing the documents provided by you with the following 2 commands:

```
PUT gos_element/_doc/AW_yu3dIa2R_HwqpSz
{
  "senderComponent": "PS",
  "timestamp": "2020-01-28T02:31:00Z",
  "activityMnemo": "PScommand",
  "activityInstanceId": "123466",
  "activityStatus": "Progress",
  "activityStatusNumber": 300,
  "specificActivityStatus": "",
  "itemNumberTotal": 10,
  "itemNumberDone": 9,
  "itemNumberInError": 0,
  "itemNumberNotStarted": 1,
  "itemNumberInProgress": 0,
  "itemUnit": "Command",
  "itemList": [],
  "contextSetId": {
    "PV": "VAR",
    "closing": "PARIS"
  },
  "correlationIdSet": {
    "closing": "PARIS",
    "businessDate": "2020-01-27",
    "correlationId": "54947df8-0e9e-4471-a2f9-9af509fb5899"
  },
  "errorSet": [],
  "kpiSet": "",
  "activitySpecificPayload": "",
  "messageGroupUUID": "54947df8-0e9e-4471-a2f9-9af509fb5899"
}


PUT gos_element/_doc/AW_yu3dIa2R_HwqpSz8z
{
  "senderComponent": "PS",
  "timestamp": "2020-01-28T03:01:00Z",
  "activityMnemo": "PScommand",
  "activityInstanceId": "123466",
  "activityStatus": "End",
  "activityStatusNumber": 200,
  "specificActivityStatus": "",
  "itemNumberTotal": 10,
  "itemNumberDone": 10,
  "itemNumberInError": 0,
  "itemNumberNotStarted": 0,
  "itemNumberInProgress": 0,
  "itemUnit": "Command",
  "itemList": [],
  "contextSetId": {
    "PV": "VAR",
    "closing": "PARIS"
  },
  "correlationIdSet": {
    "closing": "PARIS",
    "businessDate": "2020-01-27",
    "correlationId": "54947df8-0e9e-4471-a2f9-9af509fb5899"
  },
  "errorSet": [],
  "errorMessages": "",
  "kpiSet": "",
  "activitySpecificPayload": "",
  "messageGroupUUID": "54947df8-0e9e-4471-a2f9-9af509fb5899"
}
```

As a result you get back the following response (with value 10 as expected):

```
{
  "took" : 8,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "sender_comp_aggs" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "PS",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "activity_mnemo_aggs" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "PScommand",
                "doc_count" : 2,
                "activity_instance_id_aggs" : {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                  "buckets" : [
                    {
                      "key" : "123466",
                      "doc_count" : 2,
                      "business_date_aggs" : {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                        "buckets" : [
                          {
                            "key" : 1580083200000,
                            "key_as_string" : "2020-01-27T00:00:00.000Z",
                            "doc_count" : 2,
                            "context_set_id_closing_aggs" : {
                              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                              "buckets" : [
                                {
                                  "key" : "PARIS",
                                  "doc_count" : 2,
                                  "max_date_bucket_aggs" : {
                                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                                    "sum_other_doc_count" : 1,
                                    "buckets" : [
                                      {
                                        "key" : 1580180460000,
                                        "key_as_string" : "2020-01-28T03:01:00.000Z",
                                        "doc_count" : 1,
                                        "sum_done" : {
                                          "value" : 10.0
                                        }
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you for you quick reply! 
I tried moving the sum_done at the same level as the max_date_aggs. It shows me the sum of all of the items done and not the sum of the items done which have the max of timestamp.
I also tried to use buckets but I don't know how to get the sum of the field itemNumberDone. I'll add further details right away.

Comment: Oh, what you would like to achieve is something completely different. You would need to have a bucket / scope with for all documents having that max_date as value. 

Most likely you have to solve that on application side:
- 1st request: query Elasticsearch to figure out about the max_date(s)
- 2nd request: use a filters aggregation with the individual max_dates as filters to get the buckets created and then you can ask Elasticsearc to for the sum over the documents in this buckets.

I probably want to reconsider your data model anyway as you have so many nested aggregations already.

Comment: I tried buckets but I don't know how to retrieve and then sum the itemNumberDone. I'll give you the mapping and further details.

Comment: When you say "on application side". You mean create a backend that do the resquests? 
I would like to do that with only one query and no backend -if possible-.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I changed "_key" by "_term" and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two documents:

```
{
        "_type": "gos_element",
        "_id": "AW_yu3dIa2R_HwqpSz-o",
        "_score": 5.785128,
        "_source": {
          "senderComponent": "PS",
          "timestamp": "2020-01-28T02:31:00Z",
          "activityMnemo": "PScommand",
          "activityInstanceId": "123466",
          "activityStatus": "Progress",
          "activityStatusNumber": 300,
          "specificActivityStatus": "",
          "itemNumberTotal": 10,
          "itemNumberDone": 9,
          "itemNumberInError": 0,
          "itemNumberNotStarted": 1,
          "itemNumberInProgress": 0,
          "itemUnit": "Command",
          "itemList": [],
          "contextSetId": {
            "PV": "VAR",
            "closing": "PARIS"
          },
          "correlationIdSet": {
            "closing": "PARIS",
            "businessDate": "2020-01-27",
            "correlationId": "54947df8-0e9e-4471-a2f9-9af509fb5899"
          },
          "errorSet": [],
          "kpiSet": "",
          "activitySpecificPayload": "",
          "messageGroupUUID": "54947df8-0e9e-4471-a2f9-9af509fb5899"
        }
      },
      {
        "_type": "gos_element",
        "_id": "AW_yu3dIa2R_HwqpSz8z",
        "_score": 4.8696175,
        "_source": {
          "senderComponent": "PS",
          "timestamp": "2020-01-28T03:01:00Z",
          "activityMnemo": "PScommand",
          "activityInstanceId": "123466",
          "activityStatus": "End",
          "activityStatusNumber": 200,
          "specificActivityStatus": "",
          "itemNumberTotal": 10,
          "itemNumberDone": 10,
          "itemNumberInError": 0,
          "itemNumberNotStarted": 0,
          "itemNumberInProgress": 0,
          "itemUnit": "Command",
          "itemList": [],
          "contextSetId": {
            "PV": "VAR",
            "closing": "PARIS"
          },
          "correlationIdSet": {
            "closing": "PARIS",
            "businessDate": "2020-01-27",
            "correlationId": "54947df8-0e9e-4471-a2f9-9af509fb5899"
          },
          "errorSet": [],
          "errorMessages": "",
          "kpiSet": "",
          "activitySpecificPayload": "",
          "messageGroupUUID": "54947df8-0e9e-4471-a2f9-9af509fb5899"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I would like to aggregate of a few terms (senderComponent, activityMnemo ,activityInstanceId, correlationIdSet.businessDate and contextSetId.closing) and also aggregate on the max timestamp of each of these aggregations. Once this is done, I would like to sum the itemNumberDone.

If we take only these two documents and do the aggregations, I would like to get 10 itemNumberDone.

Is it possible with only one query and using buckets?